# Как читать shell code

Tags: python, c, hex, дизассемблирование

Я на многих форумах и группах просвещенные компьютерной безопасности вижу как демонстрируют payload (Полезную нагрузку) там я увидел такой код `'\x00\x44\x67\x66\xfa\x01\xe0\x44\x67\xa1\xa2\xa3\x75\x4b'` я так понял это сс 16,в статье пишут (Думаю не стоит объяснять выше написанный hex код) или (Многие поняли что делает hex код) 
Как они его читают и как понимают что там записано ?

Я попытался вывести содержимое через си и питон в итоге получил `DgfъаDgЎўЈuK` подобное

Comment: переведите это в байты и скормите дизассемблеру. Только надо учесть в каком режиме предполагается нахождение процессора в момент его выполнения

Comment: Хотя надо начать с того, для какого именно процессора данный код, приведенный в ответе asm листинг для x86 откровенная бессмыслица

Comment: строка в вопросе — это просто как строковые (str)  константы в исходном коде Питона представлены (их текстовое представление —repr: байты, соответствующие печатаемым в ascii символам, представлены как сами эти символы, остальные байты экранированы как `\xHH` последовательности. HH — это значение байта в hex). В Питоне 2, str тип представляет неизменяемую последовательность байт. Выводя их на экран, вы пытаетесь байты как текст напрямую проинтерпретировать (с помощью кодировки вашего окружения), что не имеет смысла для shell code (кроме возможно отдельных частей с данными).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как они его читают и как понимают что там записано ?

Вот так это выглядит на ASM(x86)

```
0:  00 44 67 66             add    BYTE PTR [edi+eiz*2+0x66],al
4:  fa                      cli
5:  01 e0                   add    eax,esp
7:  44                      inc    esp
8:  67 a1 a2 a3             addr16 mov eax,ds:0xa3a2
c:  75 4b                   jne    0x59
```

---

**UPD**

*Гугл подсказывет:*

Читать из чужого *пейлоада* обратно, не имеет смысла побольшему счету (его могли дать ошибочным или другая архитектура сборки и т.д.), *пейлоад* подразумивает, то что вы получаете результат при определённых условиях, которые должен вызвать этот самый *пейлоад* (то есть или вы этот результат знаете или вам нужно "писать" свой пейлод с нуля).

Под эти условия пишется программа обычно на языке, который компилируется в промежуточный файл, из этого промежуточного файла нехитрыми командами извлекаеся часть кода, которая преобразуется в строку без спец символом (обычно `\x00` и т.д.и т.п.), дабы не остановить "полезный" процесс своим появлением. Вот и весь *пейлоад*.

Вообщем так.

*П.С.*: Пусть "читатели" пейлодов, поправят.

---

**UPD:** Благодарю @AlexanderBarakin

Можно увидеть, что есть в пейлоаде, выполнив следующую команду:

```
$ echo -ne '\x00\x44\x67\x66\xfa\x01\xe0\x44\x67\xa1\xa2\xa3\x75\x4b' > /tmp/file; objdump -D -b binary -m i386 /tmp/file
```

---

[Disassemble](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2)

Comment: вместо указания какого-то сайта лучше б продемонстрировать работу дизассемблера. `$ echo -ne '\x00\x44\x67\x66\xfa\x01\xe0\x44\x67\xa1\xa2\xa3\x75\x4b' > /tmp/file; objdump -D -b binary -m i386 /tmp/file`